# Can a Model maintain the order of prediction in which the features were given to it

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

Can a model maintain the order of predictions in loss function based on the order of the batch of input features given to it while training.? if not how can i make it remember the order because i need this order in my custom loss function currently its failing which i think is because its not following the order.
for example input features are 45,12,23 and ground truth of 1,2,3 so in predictions i want the same order Such that loss function gets the predictions in the same order as the input features were.

Comment: Yes, a model does maintain the order of  predictions based on the given input value.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `tf.keras.Sequential`, the `fit()` method has a `shuffle` argument which is set to `True` by default.

You may set to `False` to avoid shuffling of samples. Note, this argument has no effect when `steps_per_epoch` argument is `None`. See the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Sequential#fit).

Comment: you are right and i did try to set it False but still there was no effect on the results.? i am defining the batches and epochs with a custom function not using built in for e.g if there are 128 samples then i can set epochs like 2 and batch size 32 so there are 4 iterations in each epoc, first it will get first 32 samples from custom generator in 2nd iteration next 32 and so on..... now i have sorted those 32 samples and given them to model with their ground truth but i want the model to remember the order of these 32 samples for my custom loss function to work.